# Most concise way to draw multiple grids in code - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I need to draw a user defined number of grids using C# WPF. My code works but is overly long if the maximum allowed number of grids is large - is there a more concise way?

The following code shows how 1 grid is currently drawn on gridCanvas (a WPF Grid Control) - it is repeated for each additional grid that may be needed.

```
private void DrawInvGrid(int[,] initialPosn)
{          
    PathFigure myPathFigure1 = new PathFigure();
    GeometryGroup myGeometryGroup1 = new GeometryGroup();
    LineSegment myLineSegment1 = new LineSegment();      
    PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection1 = new PathSegmentCollection();
    PathFigureCollection myPathFigureCollection1 = new PathFigureCollection();

    // repeat declarations for each grid

    int gridx = 5;
    int gridy = 5;
    int gridsize = 11;

    // create grid 1

    for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
    {
        int startpt_1x = (initialPosn[0, 0] - 5);
        int startpt_1y = (initialPosn[0, 1] - 5);
        for (int i = 0; i <= gridx; i++)
        {
            myPathFigure1 = new PathFigure();
            myPathSegmentCollection1 = new PathSegmentCollection();
            myPathFigure1.StartPoint = new System.Windows.Point(startpt_1x + 
                                                         (i * gridsize), startpt_1y);

            myLineSegment1 = new LineSegment();
            myLineSegment1.Point = new System.Windows.Point(startpt_1x + (i * gridsize),
                                                startpt_1y + gridy * gridsize);
            myPathSegmentCollection1.Add(myLineSegment1);
            myPathFigure1.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection1;
            myPathFigureCollection1.Add(myPathFigure1);

            xgridpos1.Add(startpt_1x + (i * gridsize));
         }

         for (int i = 0; i <= gridy; i++)
         {
             myPathFigure1 = new PathFigure();
             myPathSegmentCollection1 = new PathSegmentCollection();
             myPathFigure1.StartPoint = new System.Windows.Point(startpt_1x, startpt_1y +
                                                    (i * gridsize));
             myLineSegment1 = new LineSegment();
             myLineSegment1.Point = new System.Windows.Point(startpt_1x + gridx * 
                          ridsize, startpt_1y + (i * gridsize));
             myPathSegmentCollection1.Add(myLineSegment1);
             myPathFigure1.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection1;
             myPathFigureCollection1.Add(myPathFigure1);

             ygridpos1.Add(startpt_1y + (i * gridsize));
         }
    }  

    // repeat grid creation loop for each grid

    // display grid 1
    gridCanvas.Children.Clear();
    PathGeometry myPathGeometry1 = new PathGeometry();
    myPathGeometry1.Figures = myPathFigureCollection1;

    myPath1.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
    myPath1.StrokeThickness = 1;
    myPath1.ToolTip = gridname;
    myPath1.Data = myPathGeometry1;

    gridCanvas.Children.Add(myPath1);

    // repeat display routine for each grid
}
```

All grids are identical in any particular run - only the position of the grid (defined by `int[,] initialPosn`) varies from grid to grid. Any suggestions on more efficient alternatives appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the repetitive code into a method that takes only those values that change (the position in your case) as parameters.